# How to make kornia HomographyWarper behave like OpenCV warpPerspective?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, kornia

As the title says, I want to use HomographyWarper from kornia so that it gives the same output as OpenCV warpPerspective.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import torch
from kornia.geometry.transform import HomographyWarper
from kornia.geometry.conversions import normalize_pixel_coordinates

image_cv = cv2.imread("./COCO_train2014_000000000009.jpg")
image_cv = image_cv[0:256, 0:256]
image = torch.tensor(image_cv).permute(2, 0, 1)
image = image.to('cuda:0')
image_reshaped = image.type(torch.float32).view(1, *image.shape)

height, width, _ = image_cv.shape

homography_0_1 = torch.tensor([[ 7.8783e-01,  3.6705e-02,  2.5139e+02],
        [ 1.6186e-02,  1.0893e+00, -2.7614e+01],
        [-4.3304e-04,  7.6681e-04,  1.0000e+00]], device='cuda:0',
       dtype=torch.float64)
homography_0_2 = torch.tensor([[ 7.8938e-01,  3.5727e-02,  1.5221e+02],
        [ 1.8347e-02,  1.0921e+00, -2.8547e+01],
        [-4.3172e-04,  7.7596e-04,  1.0000e+00]], device='cuda:0',
       dtype=torch.float64)
transform_h1_h2 = torch.linalg.inv(homography_0_1).matmul(
                        homography_0_2).type(torch.float32).view(1, 3, 3)

homography_warper_1_2 = HomographyWarper(height, width, padding_mode='zeros', normalized_coordinates=True)
warped_image_torch = homography_warper_1_2(image_reshaped, transform_h1_h2)

warped_image_1_2_cv = cv2.warpPerspective(
                        image_cv,
                        transform_h1_h2.cpu().numpy().squeeze(),
                        dsize=(width, height),
                        borderMode=cv2.BORDER_REFLECT101,
                    )

cv2.namedWindow("original image")
cv2.imshow("original image", image_cv)
cv2.imshow("OpenCV warp", warped_image_1_2_cv)
cv2.imshow("Korni warp", warped_image_torch.squeeze().permute(1, 2, 0).cpu().numpy())

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

With the code above, I get the following output:

[image]
[image]
[image]

With `normalized_coordinates=False`, I get the following output:

[image]

Apparently the homography transformation is applied differently. I would love to know the difference.

Comment: How did you get the distortion arguments?  Was it from 4 pairs of corresponding points? If so, does your KorniWarp use y,x in place of x,y? What is the difference between homography_01 and homography_02 and why are there two homographies?  We are not Kornia experts. Is there a reference/link to some documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make two changes:

1. Use the same padding mode.

In your example cv2 uses `cv2.BORDER_REFLECT101` but the kornia `zeros`
So change `zeros` to `padding_mode='reflection'` when calling kornia.

2. You need to specify `normalized_homography=False`.

So the modified version:

```py
from kornia.geometry.transform.imgwarp import homography_warp
warped_image_torch = homography_warp(image_reshaped, transform_h1_h2, dsize=(height, width), padding_mode="reflection", normalized_homography=False)
```

Or simply:

```py
from kornia.geometry.transform.imgwarp import warp_perspective
warped_image_torch = warp_perspective(image_reshaped, transform_h1_h2, dsize=(height, width), padding_mode="reflection")
```

The result (cv2/kornia):

[image]

HomographyWarper internally calls `homography_warp` function https://github.com/kornia/kornia/blob/f696d2fb7313474bbaf5e73d8b5a56077248b508/kornia/geometry/transform/homography_warper.py#L96 but HomographyWarper does not provide `normalized_homography` argument and `homography_warp` does.

Complete example:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import torch
from kornia.geometry.transform.imgwarp import warp_perspective, homography_warp


image_cv = cv2.imread("./000000000009.jpg")
image_cv = image_cv[0:256, 0:256]
image = torch.tensor(image_cv).permute(2, 0, 1)
image = image.to("cuda:0")
image_reshaped = image.type(torch.float32).view(1, *image.shape)

height, width, _ = image_cv.shape

homography_0_1 = torch.tensor(
    [
        [7.8783e-01, 3.6705e-02, 2.5139e02],
        [1.6186e-02, 1.0893e00, -2.7614e01],
        [-4.3304e-04, 7.6681e-04, 1.0000e00],
    ],
    device="cuda:0",
    dtype=torch.float64,
)
homography_0_2 = torch.tensor(
    [
        [7.8938e-01, 3.5727e-02, 1.5221e02],
        [1.8347e-02, 1.0921e00, -2.8547e01],
        [-4.3172e-04, 7.7596e-04, 1.0000e00],
    ],
    device="cuda:0",
    dtype=torch.float64,
)
transform_h1_h2 = (
    torch.linalg.inv(homography_0_1)
    .matmul(homography_0_2)
    .type(torch.float32)
    .view(1, 3, 3)
)

# warped_image_torch = homography_warp(image_reshaped, transform_h1_h2, dsize=(height, width), padding_mode="reflection", normalized_homography=False)
warped_image_torch = warp_perspective(image_reshaped, transform_h1_h2, dsize=(height, width), padding_mode="reflection")

warped_image_1_2_cv = cv2.warpPerspective(
    image_cv,
    transform_h1_h2.cpu().numpy().squeeze(),
    dsize=(width, height),
    borderMode=cv2.BORDER_REFLECT101,
)

warped_kornia = warped_image_torch.cpu().numpy().squeeze().transpose(1, 2, 0).astype(np.uint8)
cv2.imwrite("kornia_warp.png", np.hstack((warped_image_1_2_cv, warped_kornia)))
```

Comment: Hey @u1234x1234. Your solution works indeed. Do you have any idea, why it doesn't work with the HomographyWarper with the same settings?

Comment: HomographyWarper internally calls `homography_warp` function https://github.com/kornia/kornia/blob/f696d2fb7313474bbaf5e73d8b5a56077248b508/kornia/geometry/transform/homography_warper.py#L96 and `HomographyWarper` does not provide `normalized_homography` argument but `homography_warp` does.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It's quite a bit confusing, this different methods all doing a bit the same but supporting different parameters/modes. OpenCV is a bit clearer IMHO.